# adding labels to diagnostic plots in R

Tags: r, plot, outliers, betareg

I have run a beta regression in R and would like to assess the residual diagnostics. I have used the plot function and obtained plots, however, the potential outliers are not labelled. How can I add the corresponding labels to the outliers?

```
breg.full <- betareg(Percentage ~ Total_testscore + Campus + Programme + 
                        Gender + SE_track + Hours_Math_SE, data = starters, # [-c(53, 24, 35), ]
                     link = "logit") # , , link.phi = NULL, type = "ML"
summary(breg.full) 
par(mfrow = c(2,3))
plot(breg.full, which = 1:6)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

I want to have something like this (without the actual pink box, but with the ID number.)
[image]

The author provides a link for this code ([http://www.de.ufpe.br/~cribari/betareg_example.zip.](http://www.de.ufpe.br/%7Ecribari/betareg_example.zip.)) however it is no longer working ...

Comment: Please, make a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages) and sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation

I couldn't see your data anywhere here, but I will use the `iris` dataset to demonstrate how this can be achieved. I'll stick to only two examples because this takes some time to code, but once you see two examples I think it will become fairly quick to recognize what is going on. I will supply a reference at the end that will be helpful too.

#### Fitting Model Data

First we can fit a regression  using the `iris` data, then turn the data into a tibble with model data using both `fortify` and `as_tibble`. I have added an index column for one of the plots later.

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Fit Model ####
fit <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length,
          data = iris)

#### Turn Model into Data Frame ####
fit.data <- fortify(fit) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(.index = 1:150)
fit.data
```

Which gives you this:

```
# A tibble: 150 × 9
   Petal…¹ Petal…²   .hat .sigma .cooksd .fitted  .resid .stdr…³ .index
     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>
 1     0.2     1.4 0.0186  0.207 8.18e-5   0.219 -0.0190 -0.0928      1
 2     0.2     1.4 0.0186  0.207 8.18e-5   0.219 -0.0190 -0.0928      2
 3     0.2     1.3 0.0197  0.207 1.23e-4   0.177  0.0226  0.111       3
 4     0.2     1.5 0.0176  0.207 7.86e-4   0.261 -0.0606 -0.296       4
 5     0.2     1.4 0.0186  0.207 8.18e-5   0.219 -0.0190 -0.0928      5
 6     0.4     1.7 0.0158  0.207 6.06e-4   0.344  0.0563  0.275       6
 7     0.3     1.4 0.0186  0.207 1.49e-3   0.219  0.0810  0.396       7
 8     0.2     1.5 0.0176  0.207 7.86e-4   0.261 -0.0606 -0.296       8
 9     0.2     1.4 0.0186  0.207 8.18e-5   0.219 -0.0190 -0.0928      9
10     0.1     1.5 0.0176  0.207 5.53e-3   0.261 -0.161  -0.785      10
# … with 140 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​Petal.Width,
#   ²​Petal.Length, ³​.stdresid
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

You can see here it gives you a lot of valuable information...residuals, fitted residuals, Cook's distance, etc. This makes it easy to plot them in `ggplot2`.

#### Plotting

The first example will be a Cook's distance plot. This takes the index of the data point and plots the columns representing their respective distance using the `geom_col` function. The key ingredient here is the `geom_text` portion. Simply subset the data and nudge it a little so it doesnt totally overlap and you can essentially label whatever you want:

```
#### Cooks Distance ####
fit.data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=.index,
             y=.cooksd,
             label=.index))+
  geom_col()+
  labs(x="Index",
       y="Cook's Distance",
       title = "Cook's Distance")+
  geom_text(data=subset(fit.data,
                         .cooksd > .05),
            nudge_y = .003)
```

Giving you this plot:

[image]

Another example using a similar method below plots fitted values versus their respective residuals, with an arbitrary label placed here was well:

```
#### Fitted vs Residuals ####
ggplot(fit.data,
       aes(.fitted,
           round(.resid,2),
           label=round(.resid,2))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)+
  labs(x="Fitted",
       y="Residual",
       title = "Fitted vs Residuals")+
  geom_text(data=subset(fit.data,
                        .resid > .5 | .resid < -.5),
            nudge_x = .09)
```

[image]

A slew of other examples of how to do this can be seen at [this link](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/fortify.lm.html). The customization will be up to you, but it should give you a fair idea of how to hand tailor some of these base R plots you are getting.